# Validate user token of multiple applications in a single OAuth2-based authentication WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am in the following scenario:

I developed an API that only serves for authentication and authorization of the company's users, which I am calling SecurityAPI. All services work as expected and the API is based on OAuth2.

In the company I have several applications and each application has its API with specific business rules.

Considering the situation where, for example, I log in by making a request to the SecurityAPI that returns me the generated Token and the same one being saved in the session, then I want to make a request of a SPA application in angular for the API with business rules application. How could I send the Token information to the security API to authenticate and / or authorize the requesting user according to the generated Token?

Comment: You might want to look at [Identity Server 4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/).

Comment: @Win But does not this only work in .NET Core? I am using the .NET Full Framework.